# Convert SQLite PHP array into Javascript array?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, sqlite, chart.js

I have an SQLite query that extracts a list of TEXT names and puts them into an array in PHP.

I then wish to convert this PHP array into a Javascript array to use in a Chart.js chart.

This worked fine with the integer values gotten from my SQLite table, and I can extract the text values fine and print them, however, I cannot seem to get the array of text values into the correct Javascript array format I need.

I am wanting to replace the line:

```
labels:['Boston', 'Worcester', 'Springfield', 'Lowell', 'Cambridge'],
```

With:

```
labels:labels_array,
```

I have tried

```
var label_array = [<?php echo implode("',", $name_array, "'"); ?>];
```

But the Chart.js doesn't seem to like it.

Is it an issue with it being TEXT, not String? Or am I not getting the correct format I'm looking for?

Comment: No, your string is just not right. PHP implode does have the following signature: `string implode ( string $glue , array $pieces )` and thus your third parameter gets ignored and you never have a closing quote mark.

Answer (score 1):

The php **[`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)** function accepts two parameters, and you're trying to pass tree, so the current implode syntax will return the wrong format, try it like :

```
var label_array = [<?php echo "'".implode("','", $name_array)."'"; ?>];
```